# How I can update or put a new object into array of object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

Basically I have an array of objects, and I have created a new object that I want to examine, I have to see if the new object contains the same keys present in my array of objects, then see if it is a completely new object and then add it, or check if it already exists and if so update it, in this case if it is already present the request is to update only the 'ingredients' property

### to be clearer this is the request

**Okay this is the request : write a function that, given a recipe, adds it to the list of recipes or modifies the ingredients if it already exists.**

*I wanted to know if it is possible to do this using a type of map function, however I repeat I have just started and I get easily confused*

```js
var ricette = [
  {
    nome: "Carbonara",
    ingredienti: ["guanciale", "uovo", "sale"],
    tipologia: "primo",
  },
  {
    nome: "Amatriciana",
    ingredienti: ["guanciale", "pecorino", "pomodoro"],
    tipologia: "primo",
  },
  {
    nome: "Cacio e Pepe",
    ingredienti: ["pepe", "pecorino"],
    tipologia: "primo",
  },
  {
    nome: "Cicoria",
    ingredienti: ["aglio", "peperoncino"],
    tipologia: "contorno",
  },
  {
    nome: "Tiramisu",
    ingredienti: ["uovo", "mascarpone", "savoiardo"],
    tipologia: "dolce",
  },
];



let nuovo = ricette.push({
    nome: "Tofu panato",
    ingredienti: ["farina", "pangrattato", "olio"],
    tipologia: "secondo",
});
```

Comment: what is your expected result? please provide in the question

Comment: `.push()` is indeed a way to add an element to an array.  It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Are you asking how to find an existing element in an array?  How to update properties on that object?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: I edited your question slightly; still some grammar issues but I tried to do some reformat to make your objectives clear, singular and complete - still needs work  but better as a list of criteria than a rambling paragraph perhaps. **Please edit to add a "before" and "after" of an updated object** so we can be as clear as possible here on your objective

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ricette = [
    {
        nome: "Carbonara",
        ingredienti: ["guanciale", "uovo", "sale"],
        tipologia: "primo",
    },
    {
        nome: "Amatriciana",
        ingredienti: ["guanciale", "pecorino", "pomodoro"],
        tipologia: "primo",
    },
    {
        nome: "Cacio e Pepe",
        ingredienti: ["pepe", "pecorino"],
        tipologia: "primo",
    },
    {
        nome: "Cicoria",
        ingredienti: ["aglio", "peperoncino"],
        tipologia: "contorno",
    },
    {
        nome: "Tiramisu",
        ingredienti: ["uovo", "mascarpone", "savoiardo"],
        tipologia: "dolce",
    },
];

function pushIfNew (array, obj){
    if (array.some(_obj=> obj.nome == _obj.nome))
        return array[array.map(_obj=>_obj.nome).indexOf(obj.nome)] = obj

    array.push(obj)
    array[array.map(_obj=>_obj.nome).indexOf(obj.nome)] = obj
    return array.length

} 


pushIfNew(ricette, {
    nome: "Amatriciana",
    ingredienti: ["farina", "pangrattato", "olio"],
    tipologia: "secondo",
}) // this updates because there's a reciepe with name Amatriciana

pushIfNew(ricette, {
    nome: "new dish",
    ingredienti: ["a", "b", "c"],
    tipologia: "secondo",
}) // this inserts new dish

console.log(ricette)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to iterate through the array and check if a matching object exists or not.

```js
var ricette = [
  {
    nome: "Carbonara",
    ingredienti: ["guanciale", "uovo", "sale"],
    tipologia: "primo",
  },
  {
    nome: "Amatriciana",
    ingredienti: ["guanciale", "pecorino", "pomodoro"],
    tipologia: "primo",
  },
  {
    nome: "Cacio e Pepe",
    ingredienti: ["pepe", "pecorino"],
    tipologia: "primo",
  },
  {
    nome: "Cicoria",
    ingredienti: ["aglio", "peperoncino"],
    tipologia: "contorno",
  },
  {
    nome: "Tiramisu",
    ingredienti: ["uovo", "mascarpone", "savoiardo"],
    tipologia: "dolce",
  },
];

let nuovo = {
  nome: "Tofu panato",
  ingredienti: ["farina", "pangrattato", "olio"],
  tipologia: "secondo",
};

let found = false;

for (let i = 0; i < ricette.length; i++) {
  // Check if the ingredients match
  if (JSON.stringify(ricette[i].ingredienti) === JSON.stringify(nuovo.ingredienti)) {
    // Update the existing object with the new data
    ricette[i] = nuovo;
    found = true;
    break; // No need to continue searching once updated
  }
}

if (!found) {
  // If no matching ingredient list was found, add the new object to the array
  ricette.push(nuovo);
}

console.log(ricette);
```